# Rails Save a record within transaction even if transaction rolls back?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, transactions

I have a series of records to save as part of a transaction.  In addition to normal AR records, I am doing a credit card gateway transaction.  If it or the AR transactions fail, I want everything rolled back ... except for the data of the failed transaction (reason, date, etc.) that I get back from the credit card gateway.  Something like

```
def pay
  Payment.transaction do
    payment.save
    other.save
    result = credit_card.purchase  # this does the gateway transaction, no database stuff
    if result.failure
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
      result.save  # this is the part I want to always save
    end
    another.save
  end
end
```

Is there a way to exclude a specific part within a transaction from rollback on failure?

Rails 3.2.5, MySQL 5.1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand why you want to do this but could you just save the credit card stuff outside of your transaction?

```
result = nil
Payment.transaction do
  payment.save
  other.save
  result = credit_card.purchase  # this does the gateway transaction, no database stuff
  if result.failure
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback      
  end
end
result.save
```

(you need to set result to nil before the transaction because of how block variable scoping works)

Another possible strategy is to use the fact that transactions are done a per connection basis. Two threads will use different connections, so you could do:

```
Payment.transaction do
  payment.save
  other.save
  result = Thread.new do
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
      credit_card.purchase.tap do |result|
        result.save
      end
    end
  end.join.value
  if result.failure 
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
end
```

or maybe just:

```
Payment.transaction do
  payment.save
  other.save
  result = credit_card.purchase
  Thread.new do
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
      result.save
    end
  end.join
  if result.failure 
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
end
```

Here the purchase happens on another thread, i.e. with its own database connection. Anything that happens in that thread won't be rolled back

Comment: Doh!  Yeah, saving the cc result outside of the transaction is probably what I want.  Sometimes the obvious answers are not apparent to me.  The thread trick is neat; I saw the warning in the docs on multiple connections, but didn't make the leap to use that to my advantage ... although a little hacky as it seems to be an artifact of implementation rather than an intentional mechanism.  Any way, awesome answer -- thanks.

Comment: Useful! Small correction: the result will be a dead thread. To get the result:
result = nil
Thread.new(result) do |result|
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
      result = credit_card.purchase
    end
  end.join

Comment: Updated to add .join. Also looked like the 2nd example was missing result.save so added that too. Haven't tested the code, so hopefully it is correct...